Next.js Hydration Error is pointing out nesting error, however none is found?
I have been stuck on this problem for a couple hours now. I am creating a shopping cart implementation that will take the cart items (which are stored in localstorage) and display them. Here is a visual of what the cart looks like currently:

All of this is stored in a component called <OuterCart />. Each of the items is a rendering of the <CartItem /> component. Here is the code for both of them:
<OrderCart />
const OuterCart = ({cart, removeItem, changeQuantity}) => {
  return (
    <div className='px-3 text-gray-800'>
      <h1 className='my-10 text-2xl font-bold'>Shopping Cart</h1>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-10'>
        <div className='col-span-5 flex flex-col mb-5 border-b text-gray-800'>
          {cart.length === 0 ? <p>You have no items in your cart. <a href="/store" className='text-indigo-600'>Go shopping</a> to add some!</p> : ""}
          {cart.map((value, index, array) => {
            return(<CartItem key={index} value={value} removeItem={removeItem} changeQuantity={changeQuantity} />)
          })}
        </div>
        <div className='col-span-1'></div>
        <CartOrder cart={cart} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

<CartItem />
const CartItem = ({value, removeItem, changeQuantity}) => {
  return (
    <div className='py-3 px-1 border-t flex grid grid-cols-3 gap-3'>
      <Image className='rounded-sm' src={img} alt='Product'></Image>

      <div className='ml-5 relative flex flex-col'>
        <span className='mb-1'>{value.name}</span>
        <span className='text-sm text-gray-500 mb-1'>{value.finish}, {value.size}</span>
        <span className='text-md'>${value.price.toFixed(2)}</span>
      </div>

      <div className='flex justify-between'>
        <div>
          <select className='outline-none border-2 border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-700 px-3 pr-[2.5rem] py-1 rounded-md h-auto' onChange={(e) => changeQuantity(e, value.cartId)}>
            {[1,2,3,4,5].map(e => (
              <option
                key={e}
                selected={e === value.quantity}
              >
                {e}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className='text-gray-400 hover:text-red-600 hover:cursor-pointer transition outline-none'>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-4 h-4" onClick={() => {removeItem(value.cartId)}}>
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

Here's the code for the page.js that puts these components together:
const Cart = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Cart - Luca Cangelosi Photography`;
  });

  let items;
  try {
    items = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cart')).items;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    items = [];
  }

  const [cart, setCart] = useState(items);

  function changeQuantity(event, cartId) {
    let newCart = [...cart];
    for (let i=0; i<cart.length; i++) {
      if (cart[i].cartId === cartId) {
        newCart[i] = {
          ...newCart[i],
          quantity: parseInt(event.target.value),
        }
      }
    }
    setCart(newCart);
    window.localStorage.setItem('cart', "{\"items\":"+JSON.stringify(newCart)+"}");
  }

  function removeItem(cartId) {
    const newCart = cart.filter((item) => item.cartId !== cartId)
    setCart(newCart); 
    window.localStorage.setItem('cart', "{\"items\":"+JSON.stringify(newCart)+"}");
  }

  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen flex flex-col'>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex-1">
        <OuterCart cart={cart} removeItem={removeItem} changeQuantity={changeQuantity} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;

The shopping cart and all of the adjustments (adjusting quantity and removing items using the on-screen <select> and X button) work properly. However, I'm getting this React Hydration Error:

Does anyone know what this could mean? I've looked into the documentation and the issues that I could run into are accessing window.localstorage and having improper nesting of tags. I've looked and all my tags seem right (I could be wrong).
It's also important to note that I'll sometimes get an error in my VSCODE console that window is not defined, even if the cart (from window.localstorage) is properly accessed and retrieved.
What is the underlying error and how would I go about fixing it?

You should always check that window is not undefined before trying to access the data in the local storage typeof window !== "undefined". Otherwise, you'll always face hydration error.

Hi @HamedJimoh, thanks! If it is undefined, what should I proceed with to get rid of this error?

After taking a peek, could you change cart.length === 0 ? ... : "" to cart.length === 0 && ...? I might be wrong, as I've never encountered that kind of error before. However, give it a try.

@Armen hi, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, that didn't work and the error was still present.

Checking that window is not undefined before accessing the data should typically get rid of the Hydration error. The error is just stating that there is a mismatch in the HTML that was rendered on the server in comparison with what's rendered on client side. Since local storage is only available in the browser,  if you try accessing it during server-side rendering, it won't be available and that would lead to different output on the server and client side. Hence, the hydration error.

firstly check this two links
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#solution-2-disabling-ssr-on-specific-components
Next.js 13 "window is not defined"
page.jsx
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

//In my opinion, you don’t need server-side rendering if all your logic is based on localStorage.
const ContentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () =>
    import("./cart").then(({ Cart }) => ({
      default: Cart,
    })),
  { ssr: false }
);

const Page = () => {
  return <>
  {/* header, nav, ...etc */}
  <ContentWithNoSSR />
  </>;
};

export default Page;

cart.jsx
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { OuterCart } from "./outer-card";

//Based on your code, below I initialize items directly instead of cart.items; I just simplified it a bit for clarity.
const initiateDefaultData = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      finish: "xxxxxxx",
      size: "xxxxxxx",
      price: 1000,
      cartId: "1",
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      finish: "xxxxxxx",
      size: "xxxxxxx",
      price: 1000,
      cartId: "2",
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ];
  
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(data));
}

initiateDefaultData()

//1 I have improved some parts of the code
export const Cart = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(() =>
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
  );

  const changeCartQuantity = ({ target: { value } }, id) => {
    //When using a setter, make sure to use it correctly. In cases like this, you should use a callback function instead of just passing a value.
    setCart((prev) => {
      const modifiedCarts = prev.map((cart) => {
        return cart.cartId === id
          ? { ...cart, quantity: parseInt(value) }
          : cart;
      });
      window.localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(modifiedCarts));
      return modifiedCarts;
    });
  };

  const removeCartById = (id) => {
    setCart((prev) => {
      const modifiedCarts = prev.filter(({ cartId }) => cartId === id);
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(modifiedCarts));
      return modifiedCarts;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
      <div className="flex-1">
        <OuterCart
          cart={cart}
          removeItem={removeCartById}
          changeQuantity={changeCartQuantity}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

alternate
//2
const getCarts = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));

const useForceUpdate = () => {
  const [_, setState] = useState(0);
  const forceUpdate = () => setState((prev) => ++prev);

  return { forceUpdate }
}

//Actually, you don’t need state because you are working with localStorage. You can use data from localStorage as if it were state and trigger a re-render when necessary using forceUpdate.
export const Cart2 = () => {
  const { forceUpdate } = useForceUpdate()
  const carts = getCarts()

  const changeCartQuantity = ({ target: { value } }, id) => {
    const carts = getCarts()
    const modifiedCarts = carts.map((cart) => {
      return cart.cartId === id ? { ...cart, quantity: parseInt(value) } : cart;
    });
    window.localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(modifiedCarts));
    forceUpdate();
  };

  const removeCartById = (id) => {
    const carts = getCarts()
    const modifiedCarts = carts.filter(({ cartId }) => cartId === id);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", modifiedCarts);

    forceUpdate();
  };

  return (
    <></>
  );
};

